# Run time error in vb.net , want to avoid a number in the list

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System

Public Class Test
   Public Shared Sub Main() 
       Dim n As Integer
       n = Console.ReadLine
       Do While n <> 42
           System.Console.WriteLine(n)
           n = Console.ReadLine
       Loop
   End Sub
End Class
```

I am getting a run time error for this code. How can I change it. and how to limit the loop to print number from 1 to 42 and not 5 in the list ?

Comment: Could you provide the error you are getting?

Comment: I guess you get compile error at `n = Console.ReadLine` because `ReadLine` returns `string`

Comment: Try  `n = CInt(Console.ReadLine)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure CInt will fail in the same fashion.  Since it's a runtime error, Option Explicit has to be off, and it's failing on the implicit conversion between String and Int.  So, CInt will explicity perform the conversion, but should still fail.  At least, I *think* that is what will happen.  If someone else can't confirm or deny, I'll test it in code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution to the runtime crash is to treat 'n' as a String and not an Integer.

```
    Dim s As String
    s = Console.ReadLine
    Do While s <> "42"
        System.Console.WriteLine(s)
        s = Console.ReadLine
    Loop
```

The runtime error will occur when the inputed value cannot be converted into an Integer with your original code.  Conversely, you could use something else, like TryParse() to handle the case where the conversion fails.

```
    Dim n As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, n)
    Do While n <> 42
        System.Console.WriteLine(n)
        Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, n)
    Loop
```

The above code will work, but any input value that fails to convert to an integer will still be written to the console.  IE if you input 'A', it will output '0'.  If you only want to print inputed numbers that are numeric and also not equal to 42 you'd need to change the above.  TryParse() does return a boolean value indicating if the parse was successful.

I hope that helps, I don't fully understand what you meant with '5' in your question.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Bala R - you are 100% correct.  Thank you for correcting my error.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the input is an integer before writing it to the console and reject other input.

```
  Dim n As Integer
  Dim input As String
  Do While n <> 42
    input = Console.ReadLine
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) AndAlso IsNumeric(input) Then
      n = CInt(input)
      System.Console.WriteLine(n)
    Else
      System.Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.")
    End If
  Loop
```